Fundamental domain of $\Gamma_1(p)$
I am learning about modular curves, and would like more example of fundamental domains of congruence subgroups. Can someone give me the answer to the following question and also give me some pointer to resources for more such examples?
I am trying to understand more about the fundamental domains for $\Gamma_1(p)$, where $p>2$ is a prime. I start to understand quite well the story for $\Gamma_0(p)$. For example, let
$$D=\Big\{z\,|\,|\rm{Re}z|\leq\frac{1}{2},|z|\geq 1\Big\}$$
be the standard fundamental domain of $\Gamma(1)=\rm{SL}_2\mathbb Z$, then a fundamental domain of $\Gamma_0(p)$ is
$$
\bigcup_{\gamma\in A} \gamma D,\quad A = \{Id, ST^i, 0\leq i\leq p-1\}.
$$
But I don't know the story for $\Gamma_1(p)$, which is a normal subgroup of index $p-1$ in $\Gamma_0(p)$.
It seems that since $\pm\Gamma_1(3)=\Gamma_0(3)$, a fundamental domain of $\Gamma_0(3)$ is also one for $\Gamma_1(3)$.
But for $p>3$, are there patterns for $\Gamma_1(p)$ starting from knowledge of $\Gamma_0(p)$? That is, are there good, conceptual choices of coset representatives of $\Gamma_1(p)\backslash \Gamma_0(p)$, to make the fundamental domain connected?
I would imagine that the fundamental domain of $\Gamma(p)$ is just the union of fundamental domains of $\Gamma_1(p)$ translated by $T^i$ for $i=0,\cdots,p-1$. Is that right?
Thanks for your help.

Say you have subgroups $\tilde{\Gamma} \subseteq \Gamma \subseteq \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of finite index and a fundamental domain $\mathcal{F}_{\Gamma}$ for $\Gamma$. Then you can obtain a fundamental domain for $\tilde{\Gamma}$ by acting with representatives of the right cosets of $\tilde{\Gamma}$ in $\Gamma$. More precisely, say you have some representatives $\gamma_1$, ..., $\gamma_n$, i.e. $\Gamma = \tilde{\Gamma} \, \gamma_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup \tilde{\Gamma} \, \gamma_n$. Then the idea is to consider something like $\gamma_1 \mathcal{F}_{\Gamma} \cup \cdots \cup \gamma_n \mathcal{F}_{\Gamma}$, but there are three important aspects to take into account:

If $\Gamma$ contains $-1$ and $\tilde{\Gamma}$ does not, then you should only take contributions from half of the cosets (since $\tilde{\Gamma} \, \gamma_i$ and $-\tilde{\Gamma} \, \gamma_i$ have identical actions on $\mathbb{H}$).
If you want to have a connected fundamental domain you need a suitable choice of coset representatives. To get an idea of how this can be done you can take a look here.
If you are working with strict fundamental domains you can get problems with elliptic points. When $\tau \in \mathcal{F}_\Gamma$ is an elliptic point fixed by some $\gamma \in \gamma_i^{-1} \, \tilde{\Gamma} \, \gamma_j$, then $\gamma_i \tau$ and $\gamma_j \tau$ are in the same $\tilde{\Gamma}$ orbit.

For your example with $\tilde{\Gamma} = \Gamma_1(3)$ and $\Gamma = \Gamma_0(3)$ the procedure above confirms that any fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(3)$ is also a fundamental domain for $\Gamma_1(3)$.
For your example with $\tilde{\Gamma} = \Gamma(n)$ and $\Gamma = \Gamma_1(n)$ the procedure above confirms that a fundamental domain for $\Gamma(n)$ is given by the union of the translations of $\Gamma_1(n)$ by $T^i$ for $i=0,...,n-1$ (ignoring possible subtleties with connectivity and elliptic points).
Edit:
Another way to obtain (non-strict) fundamental domains of subgroups $\Gamma \subseteq \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of finite index is to use Dirichlet domains. The main idea is to fix some $\tau_0 \in \mathbb{H}$ and choose from each $\Gamma$ orbit the point with minimal hyperbolic distance to $\tau_0$. If the stabilizer of $\tau_0$ contains no elements apart from $\pm 1$ you obtain the fundamental domain
$$ \mathcal{F} = \{ \tau \in \mathbb{H} \ | \ d(\tau,\tau_0) < d(\gamma\tau,\tau_0) \text{ for all } \gamma \in \Gamma \setminus \{ \pm 1\} \} \, ,$$
where $d$ is the hyperbolic distance. If $T \in \Gamma$ you cannot directly consider the limit $\tau_0 \rightarrow \infty$ (which essentially means replacing the condition $d(\tau,\tau_0) < d(\gamma\tau,\tau_0)$ by $\text{Im }\tau > \text{Im } \gamma\tau$) since that cusp is fixed by all powers of $T$. In particular, the set above would be empty. However, this can be fixed by considering
$$ \mathcal{F} = \{ \tau \in \mathbb{H} \ | \ -\tfrac{1}{2} < \text{Re } \tau < \tfrac{1}{2} \text{ and } \text{Im }\tau > \text{Im } \gamma\tau \text{ for all } \gamma \in \Gamma \setminus \langle -1,T \rangle \} \, .$$
Writing this out for $\Gamma = \Gamma_1(n)$ you obtain
$$ \mathcal{F} = \{ \tau \in \mathbb{H} \ | \ -\tfrac{1}{2} < \text{Re } \tau < \tfrac{1}{2} \} \setminus \bigcup_{\substack{c \neq 0 \\ c \equiv 0 \text{ mod } n \\ d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } n \\ (c,d) = 1 }} \{ \tau \in \mathbb{H} \ | \ |c\tau+d| \leq 1 \} \, .$$
Note that the union above can be reduced to a finite union (e.g. you only need contributions from $|d| \leq |c|$ and sufficiently small $|c|$).

Thanks for your answer. I guess for point 1, the $-1$ takes out half of the representatives, instead of just one. I was still hoping for a conceptual understanding of good coset representatives for $\Gamma_1(p)$ in $\Gamma_0(p)$. Maybe it is fruitless to insist on this, but there are good understandings for $\Gamma_0(p) < SL_2(Z)$. The linked algorithm just keeping trying the so-called three neighbors $AT, AT^{-1}, AS$ of a matrix $A$. I still don't see a pattern for $\Gamma_1(p)$ this way.

Of course, I fixed point 1, thanks!

The coset representatives for $\Gamma_1(p)$ in $\Gamma_0(p)$ must have first entries which (after reduction mod $p$) give $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$. I am not aware of a canonical choice which also has nice properties regarding the connectivity of the associated fundamental domain.
I am not sure which kind of understanding of the fundamental domains for $\Gamma_1(p)$ you would like to have. I like the description by Dirichlet domains, which here give you fundamental domains which are a vertical strip minus a finite set of half circles centered on the real axis.

I edited a bit my question to give the answer for $\Gamma_0(p)$. It would be nice if there is a corresponding answer for $\Gamma_1(p)$. Yes, the vertical strip minus a finite set of half disks centered on the real axis is what I would like to have.

I have added a part about the approach with Dirichlet domains.

Thanks for this part of Dirichlet domains. It is beautifully explained!

I see, so this Dirichlet domain construction is a totally different way to go about constructing the fundamental domain. Even for the example of $\Gamma_0(2)$, the result is totally different from the coset representative way of $D\cup SD\cup ST D$. Here the Dirichlet domain is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis, and it deletes two disks with center at $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$. Nice to know this!
